# TextFormField is not going upwards when the keyboard appears on devices on Android 10 and below

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

There's a chatRoomPage of my payment app with razorpay integration.
When I run this app on above Android 10 devices, everything works fine.
But when it comes to devices which runs 10 and below, I am getting these issues:

```
The TextFormField is not adjusting its size when keyboard appears. 
Instead of going upwards it remains at bottom.
```

Also, in the authentication page SingleChildScrollView is not really scrollable when the keyboard, even though the device size is very small and it hides other widget.

Compiled with

```
minSdkVersion 21 
targestSdkVersion 34
```

I have tried replacing expanded and flexible widget wherever i can
and i used flutter_keyboard_visibility package as well.

Nothing got resolved